# Writing macros with a large number of arguments

Tags: macros

How can I write a macro with more than 10 arguments?

Comment: Use a key-val system instead.

Comment: as Ulrike said you should use a key value syntax `width=3cm, height=...,...]` but I'll mark it as a duplicate of this one, even though the answers there try to answer the question as asked